# Difference of string length in arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've been trying to find the largest difference in length between strings of two different arrays. I put a loop within a loop to iterate and find the difference of all the string lengths.

```
function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
  if (a1 === [] || a2 === [])
    return -1;
  var result = 0;
  for (var i in a1) {
    for (var j in a2) {
      var diff = Math.abs(i.length - j.length);
      if (diff > result)
        result = diff;
    }
  }
  return result;
}
```

However, this code has been ignoring the first if statement that checks for an empty array. It also returns 0 indicating that the loop isn't working.

Comment: Thus you want to get the longest and shortest string from an array ?

Comment: Don't compare arrays to an empty array. That will never work, as the Array type is a reference type. Check that the length of each array is not zero instead.

Comment: Thanks I've changed the first if statement to check `a1.length === 0 || a2.length === 0` instead. Is there another way to check for empty arrays besides using the length property in this situation?

Comment: @James I suppose you could test `a1.hasOwnProperty(0)` to see if the array has a `0` property defined (i.e., first array index), but that makes it much less clear what you're doing. Also, it causes different results if you `delete` a property (that's eliminates the property but does not affect `length`), but if you're `delete`ing array indices then you're almost certainly doing something very wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly, you can't compare arrays in that way. Like [Renan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2263584/renan) said, Arrays are reference types. Change your check to see if there is anything within the array.

```
if (!a1.length || !a2.length)
  return -1;
```

Now on the other problem. Looping through an array in a `for` loop will set your var to be the index you're on.

Either use `forEach`:

```
function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
    ...
    var result = 0;
    a1.forEach(function(i){
       a2.forEach(function(j){
           var diff = Math.abs(i.length - j.length);
           if (diff > result)
               result = diff;
       });
   });
   return result;
}

// mxdiflg(['1','1'], ['111','1'])
```

or, change your function to get the item from the array, based on index:

```
function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
    ...
    var result = 0;
    for (var idx in a1) {
        for (var jdx in a2) {
            var diff = Math.abs(a1[idx].length - a2[jdx].length);
            if (diff > result)
                result = diff;
        }
    }
    return result;
}

// mxdiflg(['1','1'], ['11','1'])
```

As an aside, if you're using ES6, you could do this. I find it much more readable.

```
function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
  if (!a1.length || !a2.length){
    return -1;
  }

  var a1Lengths = a1.map((str) => str.length);
  var a2Lengths = a2.map((str) => str.length);

  var a1MaxLength = Math.max(...a1Lengths);
  var a2MaxLength = Math.max(...a2Lengths);

  return a2MaxLength - a1MaxLength;
}

// mxdiflg(['1','1'], ['111','1']) = 2
```

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear enough. I wanted the maximum difference in length of strings in two arrays. Not the difference between the maximum length strings of two arrays.

Comment: I had actually written another version which would find the maximum difference of length regardless of whether it was within the same string or not. `function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
  if (!a1.length || !a2.length)
    return -1;
  var newArr = [];
  newArr = newArr.concat(a1, a2).map((s) => s.length);
  return Math.abs(Math.max(...newArr) - Math.min(...newArr));
}` I got this to work at least.

Comment: Ah, OK. Yeah, just switch out one of the `Math.max` to be a `Math.min` in the ES6 one.  I can tweak the ES5 one's accordingly, if needed. Sounds like you're on the right path though.

Answer (score 0):

Replace

```
if (a1 === [] || a2 === [])
```

with

```
if (!a1.length || !a2.length)
```

(because otherwise you're comparing yor arrays to new, empty arrays, which will always be `false`)
and

```
for (var i in a1) {
  for (var j in a2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

with

```
for (var i of a1) {
  for (var j of a2) {
    ...
  }
}
```

(because `for ... in` gives you the keys / indices, not the values, i.e. [0, 1, 2, 3, ...]).

Answer (score 0):

Its because the array `a1` will never be equal to `[]`, even `[] == []` will be false, because references are being compared, not values as for numbers or strings. Check out [Operators](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators). Check a length of arrays to tell if they're empty or not.

Answer (score 0):

```
var a1 = ['aaa','aa','a'],
    a2 = ['b','bbbbbbbb','b'];


 function mxdiflg(a1, a2) {
   if (!a1.length || !a2.length)
     return -1;
   var result = 0;
   for (var i=0; i<a1.length;i+=1) {
     for (var j=0;j<a2.length;j+=1) {
       var diff = Math.abs(a1[i].length - a2[j].length);
       if (diff > result)
         result = diff;
     }
   }
   return result;
 }

 mxdiflg(a1,a2);
```

Not the best JS ever but a working copy of what you wrote

Answer (score 0):

Sort arrays by string length and then test the extremes (start and end) against each others.

```js
//Initial data
var arr1 = ["Hello", "lol", "Testing"];
var arr2 = ["Houston", "Texas", "Bi-Polar Bear"];
//"Bi-Polar Bear" is longest and "lol" is shortest.

function findLongestStringDiff(arr1, arr2) {
  function findLongest(a, b) {
    return b.length - a.length;
  }
  arr1 = arr1.sort(findLongest);
  arr2 = arr2.sort(findLongest);
  return Math.max(
    arr1[0].length - arr2[arr2.length - 1].length,
    arr2[0].length - arr1[arr1.length - 1].length
  );
}
var diff = findLongestStringDiff(arr1, arr2);
console.log(diff);
```

Answer (score 0):

There are many things wrong with your code,

1)you cannot compare arrays like that, use "typeof" instead which will check if array index exist or not.

2) the for-in loop you are using is comparing the length of array indexes which will cancel out eachother and you will get 0 as value, you should use normal for loop for this process
 this Example might help

```
 function mxdiflg(){

  var a1 =['asd','asdasd','asddfgsd'];
  var a2 = ['werw','werrewerewr','werwreewrererwer'];


 if ((typeof a1[0] !== 'undefined')&& (typeof a2[0] !== 'undefined')){

    var result = 0;
     for (var i=0;i<a1.length;i++) {
       for (var j=0;j<a2.length;j++) {
          var diff = Math.abs(a1[i].length - a2[j].length);

          if (diff > result)
               result = diff;
            }
          }
        }
      return result;

   }
```